# How to show a big table in IEEE conference clearly

Tags: latex, overleaf

I have a table in latex. here is the code for it. My problem is the table is huge and and the content of it is not clear. My paper texts are shown in two columns and the table locates in one of those columns. I appreciate if anyone can help me how can I make the table content more clear for example is it good to expand it in a new page?

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Comparing accuracy of }
\label{table1}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|cccccccccccc|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{12}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}out\_1} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{00D2CB} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{00D2CB}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{00D2CB}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{00D2CB}Accuracy result} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{00D2CB}Precision result} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}row} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Train-Test percentage} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}TP} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}FP} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}FN} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}TN} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Accuracy} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}TP} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}FP} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}FN} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}TN} & Accuracy \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10-90} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17508} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5433} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{35961} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.907638771} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{18715} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4226} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{35961} & 0.928127652 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{20-80} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17313} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5433} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{29610} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.896092735} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{18476} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4270} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{29610} & 0.918302651 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{30-70} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17097} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5433} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{23281} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.881250136} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{18223} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4307} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{23281} & 0.905825094 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{40-60} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{16587} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5429} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17256} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.86171513} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17760} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1255} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17256} & 0.891582217 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{50-50} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{16155} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5428} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{16942} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.834056465} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17338} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4245} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11142} & 0.870202884 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{60-40} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{15654} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5416} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5109} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.793025891} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{16817} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4253} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5109} & 0.837445573 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{70-30} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{14240} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8977} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.725161685} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{15373} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4264} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & 0.782858889 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{80-20} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9340} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3752} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.713412771} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9502} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3950} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & 0.72578676 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{9} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{90-10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4736} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1809} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.723605806} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4766} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1223} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & 0.722993452 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

The table in the paper is shown like the following:

[image]

I edit my code according to what you have written,

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

  \sisetup{
    table-format=1.3,
    round-mode = places,
    round-precision = 3,
 }
  

\begin{table*}[ht]
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Comparing accuracy}\label{tab:table}
    \begin{tabular}{c @{\hspace{12pt}} *5{c} S @{\hspace{12pt}} *4{c} S @{\hspace{6pt}}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{12}{c}{out\_1} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){1-12}
      & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Accuracy result}
      & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision result} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){3-7}\cmidrule(r){8-12}
      & TTP\tnote{1} & TP & FP & FN & TN & {ACC\tnote{3}} & TP & FP & FN & TN & {ACC\tnote{3}} \\
      \midrule
      1 & 10-90 & 17508 & 5433 & 8 & 35961 & 0.907638771 & 18715 & 4226 & 8 & 35961 & 0.928127652 \\
      2 & 20-80 & 17313 & 5433 & 8 & 29610 & 0.896092735 & 18476 & 4270 & 8 & 29610 & 0.918302651 \\
      3 & 30-70 & 17097 & 5433 & 8 & 23281 & 0.881250136 & 18223 & 4307 & 8 & 23281 & 0.905825094 \\
      4 & 40-60 & 16587 & 5428 & 3 & 17256 & 0.86171513  & 17760 & 4255 & 3 & 17256 & 0.891582217 \\
      5 & 50-50 & 16155 & 5428 & 3 & 11142 & 0.834056465 & 17338 & 4245 & 3 & 11142 & 0.870202884 \\
      6 & 60-40 & 15654 & 5416 & 3 & 5109  & 0.793025743 & 16817 & 4253 & 3 & 5109  & 0.837445573 \\
      7 & 70-30 & 14240 & 5397 & 0 & 0     & 0.725161685 & 15373 & 4264 & 0 & 0     & 0.782858889 \\
      8 & 80-20 & 9340  & 3752 & 0 & 0     & 0.713412771 & 9502  & 3590 & 0 & 0     & 0.72578674 \\
      9 & 90-10 & 4736  & 1809 & 0 & 0     & 0.723605806 & 4732  & 1813 & 0 & 0     & 0.722994652 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \par\tnote{1} Test Train Percentage
    \par\tnote{2} Accuracy
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make sure tables aren't too wordy; "the long" column names and insane number of decimal places are mostly the culprits!

I managed to fit the table within a page of a regular two column document. However, I changed some names to acronyms and added annotation to explain what they represent. I also reduced accuracy to 3 decimal places (I don't think you need more than 2).

There are a few additional packages in the code

- `siunitx` to round some numbers
- `threeparttable` to split the table into three parts: a caption, the main table, footnotes (*)
- `booktabs` for much better rules (**).

* If you insist on using colours, then you will have to get back to regular `\hline` due to gaps between background colours and rules defined by `booktabs`. I think a well designed table doesn't need colours
** The caption width will be reduced to the width of your table, which IMO has much better effect; move caption outside the `threeparttable` if you prefer captions to have the full page width .

Here's the result with dummy texts

[image]

and code

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
  \sisetup{
    table-format=1.3,
    round-mode = places,
    round-precision = 3,
  }
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\section{One}
\kant[1-2]

\begin{table*}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Comparing accuracy}\label{tab:table}
    \begin{tabular}{c @{\hspace{12pt}} *5{c} S @{\hspace{12pt}} *4{c} S @{\hspace{6pt}}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{12}{c}{out\_1} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){1-12}
      & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Accuracy result}
      & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Precision result} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){3-7}\cmidrule(r){8-12}
      & TTP\tnote{1} & TP & FP & FN & TN & {ACC\tnote{2}} & TP & FP & FN & TN & {ACC\tnote{2}} \\
      \midrule
      1 & 10-90 & 17508 & 5433 & 8 & 35961 & 0.907638771 & 18715 & 4226 & 8 & 35961 & 0.928127652 \\
      2 & 20-80 & 17313 & 5433 & 8 & 29610 & 0.896092735 & 18476 & 4270 & 8 & 29610 & 0.918302651 \\
      3 & 30-70 & 17097 & 5433 & 8 & 23281 & 0.881250136 & 18223 & 4307 & 8 & 23281 & 0.905825094 \\
      4 & 40-60 & 16587 & 5428 & 3 & 17256 & 0.86171513  & 17760 & 4255 & 3 & 17256 & 0.891582217 \\
      5 & 50-50 & 16155 & 5428 & 3 & 11142 & 0.834056465 & 17338 & 4245 & 3 & 11142 & 0.870202884 \\
      6 & 60-40 & 15654 & 5416 & 3 & 5109  & 0.793025743 & 16817 & 4253 & 3 & 5109  & 0.837445573 \\
      7 & 70-30 & 14240 & 5397 & 0 & 0     & 0.725161685 & 15373 & 4264 & 0 & 0     & 0.782858889 \\
      8 & 80-20 & 9340  & 3752 & 0 & 0     & 0.713412771 & 9502  & 3590 & 0 & 0     & 0.72578674 \\
      9 & 90-10 & 4736  & 1809 & 0 & 0     & 0.723605806 & 4732  & 1813 & 0 & 0     & 0.722994652 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \par\tnote{1} Test Train Percentage
    \par\tnote{2} Accuracy
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\kant[3-5]

\section{Two}
\kant[1-2]
\end{document}
```

---

#### Update

In order to achieve top alignment of a float on a single empty page, add the following to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\setlength\@dblfptop{0pt}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used your great code to adjust my table position, and I tried to remove the extra texts you added in your code. Now my problem is the table instead of being shown at the end of its above columns, it is shown in the middle of the next page while between the table and its above columns there is an empty space. I appreciate if you help me to solve it.

Comment: See my update. This is the expected effect because usually the big tables than span almost the whole page are placed on a "float page" and require central placement. Otherwise they look odd. In `twocolumn` documents, standalone floats (in starred `table*`,`figure*`) are also considered this way, except they are wider and more shallow. So the same very useful effect is more like an artifact in `twocolumn` documents.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Did you mean I have to put those lines you wrote after   \begin{threeparttable}? I did it but there is no any changes!

Comment: No, the lines need to be added before the definition of the document begins, hence in preamble--this is a section between `\documentclass{}` and `\begin{document}`.